# Swapping 3 rooks in a 3x3 grid

Tags: combinatorics, chess

This puzzle was inspired by this one: [Swapping rooks in a 4x4 board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85281/swapping-rooks-in-a-4x4-board)

What is the least number of moves required to swap black and white rooks? Rooks move using standard chess rules - any number of empty cells vertically or horizontally. You do not need to alternate players.

[image]

Comment: Is a "move" moving one space, or moving any number of spaces in one direction?

Comment: Any number of spaces. I've clarified this in the problem.

Comment: Hi Dimitry can you please help me organise my answer

Comment: @Deepthinker101 use <pre> tags like I have done. Also please hide it using the >! syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the same notation that @Deepthinker came up with, (i.e. x = black rook, o = white rook, - = empty space), I came up with the following series of steps:

Starting Position: 
`x x -` 
`x - o` 
`- o o`

1:

> `x - x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `- o o`

2:

> `x - x` 
>  `- - o` 
>  `x o o`

3:

> `- - x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `x o o`

4:

> `- o x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `x - o`

5:

> `o - x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `x - o`

6:

> `o - x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `x o -`

7:

> `o o x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `x - -`

8:

> `o o x` 
>  `x - o` 
>  `- - x`

9:

> `o o x` 
>  `- - o` 
>  `x - x`

10:

> `o o x` 
>  `o - -` 
>  `x - x`

11:

> `o o -` 
>  `o - x` 
>  `x - x`

12:

> `o o -` 
>  `o - x` 
>  `- x x`

I do not know whether or not this is the optimal strategy though. Still working on that.

Comment: Nice solution! I checked with a computer program, and this is optimal. [My code](https://gist.github.com/isaacg1/60cc20010378c585a5447bf81d9c0b2c)

Comment: well done you got it! Now can you (or anyone else) prove that this is optimal without a computer?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems almost obvious. the 12 and 32 as well as 21 and 23 rook pairs (positions : first nb horizontal, second nb vertical) cannot swap in 2 moves altogether because then they would "meet". That simply means the final positions for each rook won't be in its original row/column (obv. if we are not looking for the optimal case, they can be..) each rook needs at least 2 steps to reach their final position, so 6*2=12. So this number is the theoretical minimum

Comment: @FireCase that's correct well done!

Comment: @FIreCase, in this solution not all rooks made at least 2 steps though. the rook that moved in step 10 only made one step in total. one rook made 3 steps (the rook that moved in step 3,9 and 12). I agree that 12 is the theoretical minimum, but I'm not sure how to prove it

Comment: @Ivo yes, I see it. Maybe we could try to prove the following : it is possible for one rook to remain in its original row/column, but then another has to make at least 3 steps :P It looks difficult at the moment...