# Swapping 6 queens in a 4x4 grid

Tags: combinatorics, chess

What is the least number of moves required to swap black and white queens? Queens move using standard chess rules - any number of empty cells vertically, horizontally or diagonally in a straight line. You do not need to alternate players.

[image]

Here is a similar question for rooks: [Swapping 3 rooks in a 3x3 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102285/swapping-3-rooks-in-a-3x3-grid/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can actually be done in 17 moves.

> Step 0 
>  `Q Q Q *`  
>  `Q Q * q`  
>  `Q * q q`  
>  `* q q q`  
>  
>  Step 1 
>  `Q Q * Q`  
>  `Q Q * q`  
>  `Q * q q`  
>  `* q q q`  
>  
>  Step 2 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `Q Q * q`  
>  `Q * * q`  
>  `* q q q`  
>  
>  Step 3 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `Q Q q q`  
>  `Q * * *`  
>  `* q q q`  
>  
>  Step 4 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `Q Q q q`  
>  `* * * Q`  
>  `* q q q`  
>  
>  Step 5 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `Q Q q q`  
>  `* * q Q`  
>  `* q q *`  
>  
>  Step 6 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `* Q q q`  
>  `* * q Q`  
>  `Q q q *`  
>  
>  Step 7 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `q Q q q`  
>  `* * q Q`  
>  `Q q * *`  
>  
>  Step 8 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `q Q q q`  
>  `q * * Q`  
>  `Q q * *`  
>  
>  Step 9 
>  `Q Q q Q`  
>  `q * q q`  
>  `q * * Q`  
>  `Q q * Q`  
>  
>  Step 10 
>  `* Q q Q`  
>  `q * q q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `Q q * Q`  
>  
>  Step 11 
>  `* Q q Q`  
>  `q q q q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `Q * * Q`  
>  
>  Step 12 
>  `* Q q Q`  
>  `q q q q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* * Q Q`  
>  
>  Step 13 
>  `q Q q Q`  
>  `q * q q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* * Q Q`  
>  
>  Step 14 
>  `q * q Q`  
>  `q * q q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* Q Q Q`  
>  
>  Step 15 
>  `q q q Q`  
>  `q * * q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* Q Q Q`  
>  
>  Step 16 
>  `q q q Q`  
>  `q q * *`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* Q Q Q`  
>  
>  Step 17 
>  `q q q *`  
>  `q q * Q`  
>  `q * Q Q`  
>  `* Q Q Q`

Comment: nicely done there!

Answer (score 5):

Using the notation, (x = black queen, o = white queen, - = empty space), I came up with the following series of steps:

Starting Position:
`x x x -` 
`x x - o` 
`x - o o` 
`- o o o`

1:

> `x x - x` 
>  `x x - o` 
>  `x - o o` 
>  `- o o o`

2:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x x - o` 
>  `x - - o` 
>  `- o o o`

3:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x x - o` 
>  `- - - o` 
>  `x o o o`

4:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x x - o` 
>  `- - o o` 
>  `x o o -`

5:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x x - o` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `x o o -`

6:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x - - o` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `x o o x`

7:

> `x x o x` 
>  `x - o o` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `x o - x`

8:

> `x x o x` 
>  `- - o o` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `x o x x`

9:

> `- x o x` 
>  `- x o o` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `x o x x`

10:

> `o x o x` 
>  `- x o o` 
>  `- - - o` 
>  `x o x x`

11:

> `o x o x` 
>  `- x o o` 
>  `o - - -` 
>  `x o x x`

12:

> `o x o x` 
>  `- - o o` 
>  `o - x -` 
>  `x o x x`

13:

> `o x o x` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `o - x -` 
>  `x o x x`

14:

> `o - o x` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `o - x x` 
>  `x o x x`

15:

> `o o o x` 
>  `o - - o` 
>  `o - x x` 
>  `x - x x`

16:

> `o o o x` 
>  `o o - -` 
>  `o - x x` 
>  `x - x x`

17:

> `o o o -` 
>  `o o - x` 
>  `o - x x` 
>  `x - x x`

18:

> `o o o -` 
>  `o o - x` 
>  `o - x x` 
>  `- x x x`

This is also the solution with the least number of steps.

> To understand why, consider a 2 x 2 board with 1 black queen and 1 white queen in opposite corners.
>  
>  
>  `x -` 
>  `- o` 
>  
>  To move these queens into opposite corners, you will need to: 
>  1) Move one queen into an unoccupied square.
>  2) Move the other queen into the recently vacated square. 
>  3) Move the first queen into the recently vacated square by the other queen. 
>  
>  In essence, you need 3 moves per pair of queen. For 6 pairs of queen, you need 6 x 3 = 18 moves.

EDIT: As noted by @Bass below, the above explanation does not always hold true. So, there could theoretically be a lower limit than the one I explained.

Comment: The minimality argument doesn't scale linearly. For example, 4 queens on the sides of a 3x3 square can be colour swapped in 5 moves.

Comment: Well done! You are good at these puzzles. I wonder how this method works on larger grids?

Comment: @Bass Could I ask you for the configuration you used for your example? Is it `- x -`, `x - o`, `- o -` (from row 1 to 3)? Because this seems to require 6 steps for me.

Comment: @Alaiko [This works](https://imgur.com/a/7LCJ8TG) because you don't actually need to swap the queens pairwise, any queen of the opposing colour will do.

Comment: @Bass Yes, I see it now. Thanks! I will continue to think about the lower limit then.

Comment: In fact, I just repeated this for 6 queens in a 3 x 3 board: `x x -`, `x - o`, `- o o`. Turns out you can do that one in 8 moves. I'm starting to think this solution is not optimal after all...

Comment: you can definitely do the 3x3 version in 8 moves.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another optimal one.

> $\begin{matrix} \_&O&O&O&&\_&O&O&O&&\_&O&O&O&&\_&O&O&O\\X&\_&O&O&&X&\_&O&O&&X&\_&O&O&&X&\_&O&O\\X&X&\_&O&&X&X&\_&\_&&X&\_&\_&X&&X&\_&X&X\\X&X&X&\_&&X&X&X&O&&X&X&X&O&&X&\_&X&O \end{matrix}$
>  
>  $\begin{matrix} \_&\_&O&O&&\_&X&O&O&&\_&X&O&O&&\_&X&O&O\\X&\_&O&O&&\_&\_&O&O&&O&\_&\_&O&&O&O&\_&\_\\X&\_&X&X&&X&\_&X&X&&X&\_&X&X&&X&\_&X&X\\X&O&X&O&&X&O&X&O&&X&O&X&O&&X&O&X&O \end{matrix}$
>  
>  $\begin{matrix} \_&X&O&O&&\_&X&O&O&&\_&X&O&\_&&\_&X&O&\_\\O&O&X&\_&&O&O&\_&X&&O&O&\_&X&&O&O&\_&X\\X&\_&X&X&&X&\_&X&X&&X&\_&X&X&&\_&X&X&X\\\_&O&X&O&&\_&O&X&O&&O&O&X&O&&O&O&X&O \end{matrix}$
>  
>  $\begin{matrix} \_&X&O&X&&\_&X&O&X&&\_&X&\_&X&&\_&X&X&X\\O&O&\_&X&&O&\_&\_&X&&O&\_&\_&X&&O&\_&\_&X\\\_&\_&X&X&&\_&O&X&X&&O&O&X&X&&O&O&\_&X\\O&O&X&O&&O&O&X&O&&O&O&X&O&&O&O&X&O \end{matrix}$
>  
>  $\begin{matrix} \_&X&X&X&&\_&X&X&X\\O&\_&X&X&&O&\_&X&X\\O&O&\_&X&&O&O&\_&X\\O&O&\_&O&&O&O&O&\_ \end{matrix}$

Not correcting for symmetries there are

> 48 optimal (17 move) solutions.

A brute force program finds all of them in less than a minute.

Comment: Nice! What language are you using?

Comment: @DrXorile I'm using Python/NumPy. How did you find your solution?

Comment: Python also. Mine takes more than a minute, but I haven't optimized it too much.